# Cron jobs are not working on EC2 Aws Ubuntu 18.04 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

How you doing?

I've been trying desperately these days to achieve to run a script each 6 hours without any success, I even tried the simpliest scripts and they don't trigger at any moment, I dont know what Im doing wrong.

First I tried to add a new crontab using `crontab -e`, adding the following line:
`1 * * * * root echo "test" > /home/ubuntu/test.txt`

This cron job should be executed each minute and override the contect with the string "test", but neither it does create the file or adds the string (obviously)

I've also tried modifying the /etc/crontab file, without any success, there I've added the following line:
`* * * * * root date && echo 'it works' >> /home/ubuntu/crontest.log 2>&1`

With the same result, never it gets executed, the service is running, I made apt updates and everything and nothing seems to work, why?

Comment: Is cron service running? Try `sudo service cron status` to see the status

Comment: @JulienB. active and running since Friday (2 days ago) may restarting it help?

Comment: Well, not really :P What is the word "root" for in your crontab command?

Comment: There should be a log entry somewhere indicating that the job was run.  Check your system logs, perhaps `/var/log/syslog`.  My guess is that the job did run but didn't do anything because there is no such command as `root`.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want a crontab to run every minute, you should use `* * * * * <your command>` and not `1 * * * * <your command>` which will run the cron job every hh:01 (the first minute of every hour).

Next, the word `root` in your crontab seems a bit odd to me. Should you want to run a cron job as root, you'll normally have to create it under that user. You could try `sudo crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -u <a user> -e` to create it as "a user".

Finally, if you want a crontab to run every 6 hours, you can use `0 */6 * * * <you command>`.

Answer (score 0):

Julien B. had the answer almost since the beginning. The root keyword made my cron jobs dont wory, I thought I tried it without the root word and neither way worked, but maybe my cron syntax wasnt correct at all or wrote for longer than expected time.

Anyway, removing the keyword "root" fixes everything, thanks Julien and everyone who helped :)